# cursor within trigger for multiple update

Tags: sql-server, triggers, cursor

I have a trigger that registers the update that I do in the table `tab` and put the new and old values in a table called `history`. But this trigger is only useful for simple update such as

```
    UPDATE tab 
    set col1='value' 
    where id_tab=1
```

Since there is only one register that takes the value 1 in `id_tab`. But if I want perform an update like

```
   UPDATE tab 
   set col1='value'
   where col2=10
```

Assuming that `col2` there are several registries with value 10 and then I won't be able to perform the registration in history table. 
What can I add in my trigger? I tried to put cursors but I'm not quite sure how to approach it

```
Create table Tab 
(id_tab smallint,
col1 varchar(5),
col2 varchar(5),
)

Create table History 
(id_modify       char(3),
old_data             int,
new_data             int,
)


Create trigger tr_update
on tab
after update
as
declare curs1 scroll cursor for select col2 from tab
open curs1 
insert into History (id_modify,old_data,new_data)
select i.id_tab, d.col1, i.col1
from inserted i
inner join deleted d on i.id_tab = d.id_tab
fetch next from curso1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a cursor here just simply do as follows

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_update
ON tab
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO  History (id_modify,old_data,new_data)
    SELECT i.id_tab, d.col1, i.col1
    FROM inserted i
    INNER JOIN deleted d ON i.id_tab = d.id_tab

END
```

Comment: the virtual tales contain the data necessery for the logging operation. In the case of an update:
 inserted - the new values 
 deleted - the old ones

Comment: @M.Ali without cursor doesn't works me, why the update effected many updates in a row and the trigger without cursor is not ready to save each input and move to the next, would fail a loop with cursors

Comment: @user_012314112 have you even tested it? I can guarantee you that it will work and it will be a lot more efficient than any solution with cursor involved in it.

Comment: @M.Ali yes it works, thanks for all, but personally I'd like to know how to do this with cursors.

Comment: anything that can be done without a cursor which is pretty much everything if you are using sql server 2005 or later, you should stay away from cursors.